# How to import a digital elevation model in Germany Gauss Krüger from .dat file?

Tags: qgis, dem

i am very new to qgis.
I want to create a hillshade file and also calculate the inclination.

The structure of the digital elevation model data looks like this:

```
5390.0125 5659.9875 251.8
5390.0125 5659.9625 250.6
5390.0125 5659.9375 247.5
5390.0125 5659.9125 240.6
5390.0125 5659.8875 236.1
5390.0125 5659.8625 234.8
5390.0125 5659.8375 235.6
```

The file format is *.dat. The coordinate system is Gauss Krüger, Bessel, 5. meridian.

I have no idea how to import the data in qgis.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import it as a CSV file.

Since you're new to GIS, I suggest you follow this tutorial: [Importing Spreadsheets](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/importing_spreadsheets_csv.html).

Comment: Thank you. I hope the coordinate system of Gauss Krueger is also  taken into account there.

Comment: Hold on, you do know how to choose a coordinate system is QGIS, right?

Comment: Maybe start by finding the EPSG code.  Gauss Krüger sounds like a projected co-ordinate system, it rings the transverse Mercator map projection bell on me. Since that's german data, consider checking the german surveying authority website, they should have the info you need.